# styling twitter bootstrap ..somehow ignoring my code?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I downloaded the twitter bootstrap, then customized the starter-template.html file with the following very basic code:

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span8 outsidecontainer"> ... </div>
        <div class="span4 outsidecontainer"> ... </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

So far so good. It shows up fine and the widths are OK too. As you notice, I tried adding an "outsidecontainer" style to bootstrap.css, at the very bottom, which is:

```css
.outsidecontainer{
    padding:5px;
    background:#f2f2f2;
    border-color:#cfcfcf;
    border-width:0px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

For some reason, this styling doesn't show up though. What am I doing wrong? Something tells me it's at the very code level, not the CSS, because not even the background color changes.

Comment: Maybe you forgot to close the previous class?

Comment: Nope ..that's all there is. It looks all closed fine.

Comment: Try adding !important to each style? background-color: #f2f2f2 !important; - Just to see if something changes

Comment: Try to use Developer Tools which can tell you where all the styles come from.

Comment: Agree with above - Use Firebug / Chrome or whatever to analyze the CSS delcarations. It'll show you which rules have been overwritten and by what.

Comment: I tried Firebug but it doesn't even show the .outsidecontainer code. It's like it completely ignores it.

Comment: Is your CSS in the same stylesheet as twitter bootstrap or separate? Double check and make sure your stylesheets are linked properly.

Comment: Firefox: CTRL+U for source, click on the bootstrap CSS link, check the CSS that the broswer has, is your code in it? No? CTRL+F5 to force a none cached copy of the page.

Answer (score 0):

You've added extra padding, which will result in the spanX divs no longer fitting inside the row.

Try this instead...

```
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span8"><div class="outsidecontainer">...</div></div>
    <div class="span4"><div class="outsidecontainer">...</div></div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```